# Get text of self object in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reference

Let's say I have a button with the text 'A'.

When I click this button, I want a messagebox to appear with the text of what name of the button that was clicked.

I tried setting it to `MessageBox.Show(Me.Text)` but that just gives me the form name.

How can I refer to the text of button I just clicked?

Comment: The *Sender* that gets passed to the event handler is what you're looking for. `Sender.Name` will give you the name; if it has .Text or .Captoin, you ca retrieve that information..

Comment: `DirectCast(sender, Button).Text` works fabulously. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to handle multiple button click try following method

```
 Private Sub btn_a_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles btn_a.Click _
       ,btn_b.Click 'you can add other buttons click event here(ex. btn_c,btn_d etc)

    Dim objButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    MessageBox.Show(objButton.Text)
End Sub
```

---

[DirectCast() vs. CType()](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18320/DirectCast-Vs-CType)

Comment: The sender is not guaranteed to be the button, or even of type Button.

Comment: @SamAxe I did not get you.. BTW `btn_a_Click` or OP's `buttonname_click` accepts the sender as button unless OP addes other control's event  after _Handles_ keyword , isn't it?? . *The sender is not guaranteed to be the button* > why??

Comment: As you said, the event could handle multiple controls, not all of which need to be buttons.  And second, if at any point the OP decides to do any UI automation or UI testing then calling the click handler directly, like `btn_a_Click(Nothing, New EventArgs)` would cause an exception.  Defensive programming dictates that you check for null and check the type of a variable, `sender`, before casting it.

Comment: I upvoted your answer.  These comments are just to help round out the picture.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `MessageBox.Show(Me.Text)` didn't work is that `Me` refers the class containing the code, in this case, the Form).

If your button's event handler only handles one button, you can just hard code the buttons name like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MessageBox.Show(Button1.Text)
End Sub
```

If the event handler can handle more than one button, you can use the `sender` argument to reference the button being clicked:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
    Dim but as Button = CType(sender, Button)
    MessageBox.Show(but.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the difference between the second way you do it and `MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(sender, Button).Text)`

Comment: @IdkHowToCodeAtAll the second way creates a variable (`but`) that you might want to use in other statements. Both CType and DirectCast will get you a Button object that you can use.